# Как получить список папок на Amazon S3 Ruby gem 'aws-sdk'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

У меня бекапы хранятся на Amazon S3. Структура папок такая

```
my-bucket
 - db_backup
   - ......
   - 2017.02.20.03.30.03
     - db_backup.tar
   - 2017.02.21.03.30.04
     - db_backup.tar
```

мне бы хотелось сделать rake task который бы взял с S3 самый свежий бекап и развернул мне его локально.
для этого я решил использовать `gem 'aws-sdk', '2.7.11'`

код ниже, скачивает бекап по конкретно указанному пути и это успешно работает.

```
Aws::S3::Client.new.get_object(bucket: 'my-bucket', key: 'db_backup/2017.02.21.03.30.03/db_backup.tar', response_target: 'tmp/db_backup.tar')
```

но мне бы хотелось, что бы автоматически выбиралась самая свежая папка вместо `2017.02.21.03.30.03/` 
подскажите пожалуйста как получить самую свежую папку в папке `db_backup/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прям в [README](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) есть такие сниппеты:

```
# list the first two objects in a bucket
resp = s3.list_objects(bucket: 'aws-sdk-core', max_keys: 2)
resp.contents.each do |object|
  puts "#{object.key} => #{object.etag}"
end

# single object operations
obj = bucket.object('hello')
obj.put(body:'Hello World!')
obj.etag
obj.delete

# yields one response object per API call made, this will enumerate
# EVERY object in the named bucket
s3.list_objects(bucket:'aws-sdk').each do |response|
  puts response.contents.map(&:key)
end
```

Никогда не пользовался этим гемом и вообще S3, но наверное имя самого свежего бэкапа достается как-то так:

```
s3.bucket("my-bucket").object("db_backup").contents.map(&:key).max
```

Comment: спасибо. получилось как то так
`key = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket('my-bucket').objects(prefix: 'db_backup').map(&:key).max`
     и `Aws::S3::Client.new.get_object(bucket: 'my-bucket', key: key, response_target: 'tmp/db_backup.tar')`